# Prevent RedirectStandardError being written to console

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, stderr

I'm trying to read and parse error output of another process in a console application.

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ps, arg)
 {
   RedirectStandardError = true,
   UseShellExecute = false
 };
 Process p = Process.Start(psi);
 return p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

While this works and the whole standard error text is also returned, the text also appears on my console, which is disturbing to the user. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also redirecting standard output (RedirectStandardOutput = true) - I've had it a couple of times where the other process outputs on both.
As the other process isn't your code (I'm guessing), it's not a bad plan to take as much control of it as you can!